# Madlibs program throws ValueError

Tags: python-2.7

I'm learning Python through Codeacademy, and I'm having trouble with their Madlibs exercise. I've viewed the walkthrough after I began having trouble, but I can't see any differences between their code and mode. This is my code:

```
STORY = "This morning % woke up feeling %. 'It is going to be a % day!' Outside, a bunch of %s were protesting to keep % in stores. They began to % to the rhythm of the %, which made all the %s very %. Concerned, % texted %, who flew % to % and dropped % in a puddle of frozen %. % woke up in the year %, in a world where %s ruled the world."

print "Let the Madlibs begin!"

name = raw_input("Enter a name: ")

print "Please provide three adjectives: "
adj_1 = raw_input("1: ")
adj_2 = raw_input("2: ")
adj_3 = raw_input("3: ")

verb = raw_input("Enter a verb: ")

print "Now, input two nouns:"
noun_1 = raw_input("1: ")
noun_2 = raw_input("2: ")

print "Please provide a word for:"
animal = raw_input("An animal: ")
food = raw_input("A food: ")
fruit = raw_input("A fruit: ")
superhero = raw_input("A superhero: ")
country = raw_input("A country: ")
dessert = raw_input("A dessert: ")
year = raw_input("A year: ")

print STORY % (name, adj_1, adj_2, animal, food, verb, noun_1, noun_2, adj_3, name, superhero, name, country, name, dessert, name, year, noun_2)
```

When I run the program, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Madlibs.py", line 34, in
>   
>       print STORY % (name, adj_1, adj_2, animal, food, v erb, noun_1, noun_2, adj_3, name, superhero, name, cou ntry, name, dessert, name,
>   year, noun_2) ValueError: unsupported format character 'w' (0x77) at 
>   index 15

Please help me see what I'm missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string (`STORY`) has some invalid placeholders in it. When you're formatting a string, you have to specify what type of data will be put at each placeholder. You do this by putting a letter after the `%` sign. In this case, since you're always putting in a string, that should be an `s`. So, `STORY` should start like this:

```
STORY = "This morning %s woke up feeling %s. [...]"
```

There are more details about this syntax in [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), which explains how to do things like format numbers in a certain way.

(However, it's worth bearing in mind that in modern Python we normally use  [a newer syntax using `str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), which looks like this:

```
STORY = "This morning {name} woke up feeling {adj_1}. [...]"
print STORY.format(name="James", adj_1="terrible")
```

)

Comment: That was it! Thanks. Can't believe I forgot the s's. Cheers!

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. That way the question will be marked resolved.